# Socket IO first emit has a delay

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

So i have setup socket with express and using it in conjunction with react.  I have noticed that the first emit I send will get delayed anywhere between a couple seconds to ten seconds.

However, while the first emit is "hanging" i can send other emits that "force" the first emit to be sent immediately.

It's like the first emit has a delay then the server "wakes up" when a second emit comes in.

Then the pattern repeats.

here is my code:

(client topmost React component)

```
 testerSocketButton(){
    var sendDate = new Date();
    var stepCounter = this.state.stepCounter;
    console.log("testerSocket Called @: " + sendDate + " // " + stepCounter);
    this.setState((prevState)=>{
      return {stepCounter: prevState.stepCounter + 1}
    }, ()=>{
      console.log("test-message", new Date().toString() + " // Press # " + stepCounter);
      socket.emit("test-message", sendDate.toString() + " // Press # " + stepCounter);
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>  
        <div onClick={this.testerSocketButton}> TEST SOCKET </div>
      </div>
    );
```

(server app.js)

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const port = 8000;
const app = require("express")();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("Client connected");
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
    });
  socket.on("test-message", testMsg=>{console.log("Test message received.\n Date from client: " + testMsg + "\n Date from server: "  + new Date())});
});
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

EDIT: 
Okay I adjusted my testing with a counter as well to see if the messages were out of order.  My assumption was wrong and they are not.  They are still "delayed" though unless I force an emit with another emit where it seems to push the next one through immediately.

EDIT 2:  I tried four separate times basically clicking my button trigger in succession four times quick.  You will notice every fourth time there is a delay.

DEBUG MODE RESULTS:

```
  engine:ws received "42["test-message","Mon Jan 29 2018 22:39:23 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 1"]" +11s
  engine:socket packet +1ms
  socket.io-parser decoded 2["test-message","Mon Jan 29 2018 22:39:23 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 1"] as {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["test-message","Mon Jan 29 2018 22:39:23 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 1"]} +11s
  socket.io:socket got packet {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["test-message","Mon Jan 29 2018 22:39:23 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 1"]} +25s
  socket.io:socket emitting event ["test-message","Mon Jan 29 2018 22:39:23 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 1"] +1ms
  socket.io:socket dispatching an event ["test-message","Mon Jan 29 2018 22:39:23 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 1"] +0ms
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 22:39:23 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 1
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 22:39:37 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
  engine:ws received "2" +14s
```

Server Results:

```
    Test message received.
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 0
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 1
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:42 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:42 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 2
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:42 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:42 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 3
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:48 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 4
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 5
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 6
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:56 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:56 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 7
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:13 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:16 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 8
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:16 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:16 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 9
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:17 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:17 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 10
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:17 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:17 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 11
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:38 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 12
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 13
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 14
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
Test message received.
 Date from client: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 15
 Date from server: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:48 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

Client Results:

```
testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 0
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 0
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 1
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 1
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:42 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 2
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:42 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 2
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:42 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 3
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:42 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 3
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 4
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 4
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 5
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 5
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 6
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:55 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 6
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:56 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 7
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:57:56 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 7
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:16 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 8
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:16 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 8
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:16 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 9
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:16 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 9
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:17 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 10
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:17 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 10
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:17 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 11
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:17 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 11
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 12
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 12
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 13
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 13
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 14
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 14
App.js:293 testerSocket Called @: Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // 15
App.js:297 test-message Mon Jan 29 2018 19:58:43 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) // Press # 15
```

Comment: Is node.js directly web-facing or are you proxying? The reason I ask is that this sounds similar to (but not the same as) an issue I had with nginx awhile back.

Comment: The socket.io client sends emits serially in FIFO order and the server processes them serially in FIFO order so what you describe with all the assumptions you have does not seem possible.  So, one of your assumptions must be wrong.  Any chance, you aren't actually sending the message when you think you are?  Doing a whole bunch of `console.log()` statements that include the current time in them is probably helpful to understand the actual sequence of events in both client and server.

Comment: @jdfriend00 

I've included my testing in the original post.

Comment: When logging times, you usually want milliseconds, not just seconds.  And, you need to identify which message is which so you know which server receipt corresponds with which client message send.  And, I think we'd need to see a lot more of client code to see how this all works.

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated it with a counter, it seems they are not out of order but the emit is being delayed unless "forced" by another emit immediately after.  As you can see from the last emit on my refined results.

Comment: What controls the callback to `this.setState()` that sends your `.emit()`?  Could the problem be there?  Is the problem different if you just put the `emit()` as the first line of `testerSocketButton()` as a test?

Comment: @jfriend00  That callback is saying "after the state has been updated, lets send the emit".  Because state is updated asynchronously, it avoids potentially sending the wrong value.  In this case that value is our counter.  It doesn't matter if it's used in this context or not, same thing.

Comment: But that's what controls WHEN your `.emit()` is called and I thought you said that was the issue.  I'd suggest adding a logging of the client time INSIDE the callback on the line right before `.emit()` so you can see both when `testerSocketButton()` is called AND when `.emit()` is called in the callback.

Comment: Also, your counter isn't necessarily reliable to show you which press it really was because you are outputting the counter from `this.state`.  A reliable output would get the state at the very beginning of `testerSocketButton()` into a local variable and output that so you know you're outputting the state as it was when this function was called.  I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with the two callbacks associated with `this.setState()` (which I guess is reactjs stuff).

Comment: @jfriend00 updated

Comment: It seems like at message 7, on the client you have an 8 second delay between when  `testerSocketButton()` is called and when the callback that sends the corresponding `.emit()` gets called.  That appears to be something going on inside of `this.setState()`, right?

Comment: @jfriend00  sorry i fixed those log messages because they were confusing and redid the test.  hopefully this is more clear.  the "called @" message is when the function is called, the one below is in the callback.  As far as I can see there is no descrepancy there.  On the server side however i'm seeing seven second delays unless the emit is "forced" by another emit.

Comment: One theory is that the client gets hung up for awhile trying to send message #7.  Assuming you didn't wait 20 seconds to do button press #8, but it wasn't processed until 20 seconds after #7, then something happened in the client to keep it busy for 20 seconds.  So rather than your theory that button press #8 is what causes #7 to get sent, I'd theorize that something about sending #7 takes 20 seconds so it doesn't actually get sent for 20 seconds and only then can it get onto processing #8.  You could test that theory out by making every press be a fixed time apart like every 2 seconds.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your persistence in helping.  I was able to find the issue and it is something related to socket io, uWebSockets and Win10.  Have found a temporary workaround for now!

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: @jfriend00 Please see the edit I made at the top of my original post.

Comment: You should not put the answer in your question.  Here on stackoverflow, questions are for questions, answers are for answer. Instead, you should write an answer that explains what went wrong.  You are allowed to answer your own questions and, after an appropriate waiting period, you can even accept your own answers.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a socket io and uWebSocket issue in Windows 10 reported here for anyone else wondering: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3100**

**CURRENT WORKAROUND:**

> A workaround is to change the wsEngine to ws in the options:
>   const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, { wsEngine: 'ws' });